# WatchKit Option to ONLY Dictate?

Tags: ios, watchkit, dictation

I use:

```
 NSArray* initialPhrases = @[@"Let's do lunch.", @"Can we meet tomorrow?", @"When are you free?"];
    [self presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:initialPhrases
                                   allowedInputMode:WKTextInputModePlain
                                         completion:^(NSArray *results) {
                                             if (results && results.count > 0) {
                                                 id aResult = [results objectAtIndex:0];
                                                 // Use the string or image.
                                             }
                                             else {
                                                 // Nothing was selected.
                                             }
                                         }];
```

This is the example given for text input by Apple.  However, in my app, I want the user to ONLY have the option to dictate text.  If I set the array to nil, the dictate button is not there, but if I leave the array alone, the dictate button reappears.  Is there any way at all to do text input ONLY by dictation?

UPDATE:
Apple does have documentation that says if you are sending users straight to dictation, to not provide any responses and send them straight there.  Am I correct in gathering that the reason I don't see anything when initialPhrases is nil is just due to simulator restrictions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Dev evangelists in the forums have noted that the simulator won't show anything for dictation, owing to its lack of support.

Make sure you're using `WKTextInputModePlain` and the `suggestions` array is `nil` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  Always tough to develop for a product that you can't actually test it on yet.

Answer (score 0):

As of WatchOS 2.1, and iOS 9, I have been able to what you propose, in 2 different  ways, give me a Green Tick and upvote if it works!!:

OPTION 1 - RECORD WAV FILE AND UPLOAD TO ASR SERVER
I recorded and saved a WAV file to the apple watch. After that I uploaded the file to a paid Speech Recognition provider and everything worked fine! Here is the code to record, replace the UI updating lines of code (and the debug ones) with your own:

```
//RECORD AUDIO SAMPLE
    var saveUrl: NSURL? //this var is initialized in the awakeWithContext method//
    func recordAudio(){
        let duration = NSTimeInterval(5)
        let recordOptions =
        [WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey : duration]
       // print("Recording to: "+(saveUrl?.description)!)
        //CONSTRUCT AUDIO FILE URL
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let container = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.artivoice.applewatch");
        let fileName = "audio.wav"
        saveUrl = container?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL(saveUrl!,
            preset: .WideBandSpeech,
            options: recordOptions,
            completion: { saved, error in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err.description)
                    self.sendMessageToPhone("Recording error: "+err.description)
                }
                if saved {
                    self.btnPlay.setEnabled(true)
                    self.sendMessageToPhone("Audio was saved successfully.")
                    print("Audio Saved")
                    self.uploadAudioSample()
                }
        })
    }
```

OPTION 2 - USE THE iWATCH's NATIVE SPEECH RECOGNITION
In this approach I take the original, native voice menu, but...! I don't add any button options, just pure ASR. I launched the empty voice menu, and then recover the string returned by the ASR. Here's the code, enjoy:

```
func launchIWatchVoiceRecognition(){
     //you can see the empty array [], add options if it suits you well
        self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions([], allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.Plain, completion:{(results) -> Void in
            let aResult = results?[0] as? String
            if(!(aResult == nil)){
                print(aResult) //print result
                self.sendMessageToPhone("Native ASR says:  "+aResult!)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.txtWatch.setText(aResult) //show result on UI
                }
            }//end if
        })//end show voice menu
    }
```

OPTION 2 is lightning fast, but OPTION 1 can be more handy if you want to do some advanced speech recon functions (custom vocabularies, grammar...) I would recommend OPTION 1 for most users.
Voila!! If you need extra hints let me know!