# Watchkit: Single Tap Text Dictation through WKInterfaceController

Tags: ios, watchkit, speech-to-text, dictation

According to Apple's doc of [WKInterfaceController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/WKTextInputMode) you can let user to dictate text preseting a new interface controller in this very simple way:

```
self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["suggestion 1", "suggestion 2"] allowedInputMode: .Plain, completion: { (answers) -> Void in
if reply && reply.count > 0 {
    if let answer = answers[0] as? String {
        println("\answer")
    }
}
```

})

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984678/watchkit-speech-to-text-conversion-in-watchkit-apps).

I have seen that Amazon App for Apple Watch let you search for products by tapping the search icon directly

[image]

So you get into the Dictation in one step

[image]

Through the `WKInterfaceController` method, we will get something different

[image]

Which Apple's API Amazon app is using to enable dictation in this way?

(UPDATE)
I have just find out that it's super easy as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159358/watchkit-option-to-only-dictate?rq=1)

So the final solution I came out was this

```
    - (void) table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
if (rowIndex==0) { // handle manual selection
    __weak MainInterfaceController *weakSelf = self;
    [self presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:nil allowedInputMode:WKTextInputModePlain completion:^(NSArray *results) {
       if(results && [results count]>0) {
           NSString *inputText=nil;
           for(NSString *input in results) {
               NSLog(@"Input %@", input);
               inputText=input;
               break;
           }
           if(inputText!=nil && [inputText length]>0) {
               [weakSelf pushControllerWithName:@"Search" context:
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 inputText, @"query", nil]
                ];
           }
       } else {
           NSLog(@"No input provided");
       }
   }];
}}
```

Comment: FYI, that's just using the same link you added in your edit.

Comment: @thegrinner thanks I have found that one later.

Answer (score 2):

Set the mode to `.Plain` and don't provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the suggested strings array, it will go straight into dictation mode.